# Does minitest have its own regex syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, minitest

I was trying to test my `response.body` with regex, to make up for shifts in time zones due to daylight saving. For that I wrote following assert:

```rb
assert_match(/data-timer-timezone-value=\\"-[7|8]\\"/, response.body)
```

The tests fails, and gives me following result (not full `response.body` shown, due to size):

```bash
Expected /data-timer-timezone-value=\\"-[7|8]\\"/ to match
<h1 class=\"text-center\">Tracky</h1>\n    
<div class=\"w-100 mt-3\" data-timer-session-container>\n      
   <div class=\"box\" data-controller=\"form timer\" data-timer-timezone-value=\"-7\">\n  
      <div class=\"timer-container\">\n    
         <form class=\"new_timer_session\" id=\"new_timer_session\" action=\"/time_tracker/start\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" data-remote=\"true\" name=\"new_timer_session-604fb9d8\" method=\"post\">
```

You can see, that there should be a match on line 3 of the html.
Even regex101 tells me, it should work:
https://regex101.com/r/LdiBlY/1

Comment: It is a common issue to test against a string literal instead of a literal string. [Here is the real test](https://regex101.com/r/CASyr4/1) at regex101. And you need [this one](https://regex101.com/r/CASyr4/2).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you did to make my regex not match anymore?

Comment: Removed unnecessary backslashes.

Comment: Use Nokogiri instead to parse the HTML. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/544825